# Formatting datetime values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am retrieving date and time using this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate())
```

and it shows me output as:

```
Jul  3 2012  9:34PM
```

but client want that there should be space between time and AM/PM, means output should be like this:

```
Jul  3 2012  9:34 PM
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For one, [don't use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). And you can use `STUFF` here, e.g.

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE()), 18, 0, ' ');
```

Results:

```
Jul  3 2012 12:48 PM
```

Note that this can look different depending on language and regional settings.

In SQL Server 2012 this is a little more intuitive, however the extra space between month and day when the day is < 10 is tricky to work around (or my understanding of .NET's `format` is lacking):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM d yyyy hh:mm tt');
```